# Multiple IAP (In App Purchase)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to obtain a single receipt for multiple products purchase (iOS In App Purchase)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is what happens when you restore your purchases and have made several purchases in the past.

You will have a receipt containing every transaction made in the past.

If you are looking to make a purchase of multiple products at the same time this is not available on iOS. Android released a way to [support multi-line subscriptions](https://youtu.be/iBxYrEkpCac?t=453).